# adding localhost to mongo atlas whitelist

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I've been using the option allow everyone connection to my atlas cluster by selecting the "Allow Access from Anywhere" button in the group IP whitelist. 
Is there a way to just add my localhost ip address instead. I tried doing it but I got the following error :

```
/me/node_modules/mongodb/lib/replset.js:364
          process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                        ^
MongoError: connection 4 to cluster0blbla.net:27017 closed
```

Anyone know of a way to add localhost connection without opening security up to everyone ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can always add your local IP Address by going to:

Security - > IP Whitelist and then add a new IP.  There you can click "ADD CURRENT IP ADDRESS" along with any comment:

[image: Atlas Whitelist]

Comment: Well that was easy. Now I feel completely stupid and blind. Thanks you :)